# Where do I set environment variables on my Django Digital Ocean server?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm running my Django project on my Ubuntu 16.04 Digital Ocean server running Gunicorn/Nginx. I have my whole project except my `settings.py` file so am looking do add that in now - however don't want to hardcode the `SECRET_KEY` - so am looking to define an environment variable like it says in the Django docs: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']`.

Where do I define this variable? Is it in my gunicorn config file (`/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`)

Comment: Have a wee look at `python-decouple` https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple

Comment: Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: Yes my virtual environment is the `env` folder in my root directory (alongside `manage.py`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create environmental variables inside your .bashrc file in your home folder.
Just open the .bashrc file from home folder

```
sudo vi ~/.bashrc
```

And then at the end of the file, add your variable

```
export SECRET_KEY='your secret key'
```

then save it, and try running source command on the file so as to enable the variable(So that it gets applied without restarting the system)

```
source ~/.bashrc
```